# Syntax error near unexpected token `newline' while installing Predictionio

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm new to Prediction.io and when I try to install it following the instruction at [this page](https://docs.prediction.io/install/) I get the following error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' 
bash: -c: line 0: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
```

The command I'm executing is

```
bash -c "$(curl -s https://install.prediction.io/install.sh)"
```

How can I solve this? What went wrong?

Comment: You forgot to close your quote?

Comment: Great Observation! It was a typo error when writing the question but the command stills shows the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the file that you're putting between the quotes, to execute as a `bash` command, is a 15917 byte `bash` *script* (written by Somebody Else, and you're running it without inspection, but that's off topic). If you split it up into simpler commands, you could:

```
curl -s https://install.prediction.io/install.sh >install.sh
# inspect install.sh here
bash ./install.sh
# if it fails, do bash -x ./install.sh
rm ./install.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax would be:

```
curl -sSL https://install.prediction.io/install.sh | sh
```

or

```
wget -qO- https://install.prediction.io/install.sh | sh
```